Blazor folder uploads
This might be something very basic. We have developed a Blazor server application that can manage files for our internal staff. We implemented a zip file uploading method to upload folders (application extracts it in the server) as folder uploading is not currently supported in Blazor (At least that's what I found during initial research).
But users are requesting us to make it possible to upload folders just like we can do in OneDrive/ Google drive.
How to implement this function. We are willing to use JS if it's required.
We used .net core 7.
And we are using a InputFile to grab the files

Here’s all you need to do it: HTML File inputs have an underdocumented  folder mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

Thanks mate. But the documentation says we can select only folders or file at a given time and not both. So is there a workaround to accept both files and folders?

When you say "just like we can do in OneDrive/ Google drive" are you referring to accessing OneDrive/GoogleDrive in a web-browser and OneDrive/GDrive's file-upload functionality (in the browser) is an OpenFolderDialog? Or are you saying that OneDrive/GDrive (again, in the browser) only has an OpenFileDialog there, but an OpenFolderDialog in their native/desktop programs? Or am I missing something?

I mean we can upload a folder or a file or both to google drive in the browser right?
